# Why is monitor not sensing display signal from MacBook Pro via USB-C?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, usb-c

I bought one of the newer USB-C monitors ([Arzopa 14" A1 Gamut slim](https://www.arzopa.com/products/a1s-14-fhd-portable-monitor?_pos=1&_sid=27c9125fc&_ss=r)), and was able to utilize it connected to a new Windows laptop using only the USB-C connector with no external power connection.

However when I plug the monitor into my 2017 15" MacBook Pro (running Ventura; 13.x), I see that the monitor has power since it displays its logo and allows switching of the input, however it says "no signal received" and goes into screensaver mode

It only works if I connect it to the Mac through a USB-C to HDMI adapter but I don’t want to have to plug in a separate power cord.

Is there a trick or some setting I can change on the MacBook Pro to make it output the display signal directly over USB-C instead of through the adapter?